# Replace words but only after a colon

Tags: sed

I have been researching this for quite some time but cannot seem to find an answer.  Perhaps someone here can help.

I am trying to use sed to replace words in yml / yaml files.  Since some of the words are included in the names I want to only replace words that appear after the colon (':').

For example.  If the .yml file includes:

```
en:
  label_some_tracker: A tracker
  label_all_tracker: All trackers
  label_attachment_type_trackers: Select trackers.
  tracker_plural: trackers
```

and I want to replace all occurrences of tracker with issue in all values.  The pattern:

```
s/tracker/issue/
```

also changes the names of the fields, which breaks my code.

I can reduce the size of the problem somewhat by including terms for all possible variants of a word.  For example:

```
s/trackers/issues/
s/tracker/issue/
```

but that doesn't deal with all situations.

I have tried inserting a space before the search term:

```
s/ tracker/ issue/
```

but that matches names where the search term is at the beginning of the line.

If I search for whole words then it still seems to pick up the names because ':' and '_' are 'non word' characters.

If I try to put spaces at the beginning and end of the search term but then it misses words that are at the end of a line or words patterns with punctuation marks before the training space.

The only sure way seems to be to only replace words after a colon (':') but I cannot seem to figure out how to do that with sed.

Does anyone here know how?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/(:.*)tracker/\1issue/g' file
```

Output:

```
en:
  label_some_tracker: A issue
  label_all_tracker: All issues
  label_attachment_type_trackers: Select issues.
  tracker_plural: issues
```

Comment: The `g` flag is not necessary (with the data provided) as the `.*` is greedy and will swallow all other occurrences of `:` and `tracker`.

Comment: Many Thanks!  I will give that a try.

Comment: @potong: yes, `g` is useless. I need a conditional jump to replace all of them: `sed -E ':a; s/(:.*)tracker/\1issue/; ta' file`

Answer (score 0):

Replace second occurance:

```
 sed 's/tracker/issue/2' file
```